# Verificar se existem produtos ativos nessa marca, se não tiver, não mostrar marca

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine

Tenho duas tabelas no meu banco, `adm_marca` e `adm_produto`, no momento, está mostrando na minha view todos as marcas, independente se existem produtos ativos ou não, eu preciso que mostre somente as marcas que não possuam produtos ativos. Como fazer essa verificação?

Minha view:

```
  <?php foreach ($marcas as $marca) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url("marca/" . $marca->getSlug()); ?>"><?php echo $marca->getNome(); ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Marca_model:

```
  public function marcas(){
   return $this->doctrine->em->getRepository("Entity\AdmMarca")->findBy(array('status'=> 1));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode aproveitar este método "marcas" existente, ou criar um separado somente para produtos ativos. Nos dois casos, basta adicionar a regra do doctrine:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->not($qb->expr()->exists($sub->getDQL())));
```

Referência: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: O problema é que eu teria que fazer um inner join, a unica relação que tenho entre as tabelas é a tabela de produtos que contem o ID da marca. Porém se eu criar um método que pegue a tabela de produtos para validar, não consigo trazer as marcas em si.

Comment: Então utilize o not(), modifiquei a resposta ali!